# Inherit background color from SharePoint 2013 theme

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, theme, cssregistration

Are there any ways to inherit background color of SharePoint theme for any class in a webpart? (That's mean when site theme changed, the css color of classes in my webpart also being changed).

Comment: I have same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link to resolve my problem :-)

https://bniaulin.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/step-by-step-create-a-sharepoint-2013-composed-look/